# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition when in background on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, browser, navigator

In a webpage on an Android browser like Kiwi browser (a chromium/chrome based browser), when I run this kind of code,

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
  console.log(position.coords);
})
```

while it shows the result successfully when the page is shown on the phone, it doesn't show the result but it stucks on the callback calling when the page is hidden (like, when you're on an another tab on the browser, or on the home screen or on an another app) on the phone.

I'm not interested in knowing the why, because I know a guy says "it becauses if it's possible it can be a vulnerability" or something similar. I'm interested in how to get around the problem. I guess like through a phone setting, developer setting, kiwi setting, javascript, etc (but I prefer not rooting related, but if rooting is necessary and only possible way around I'm okay to take the solution).

Is it possible in any way? Thanks for your help.